# Не получается переустановить Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bios, live-usb

Проблема случилась 2 дня назад. В ноутбуке установлено 2 системы : Windows 10 и Ubuntu. Недавно обновил виндоус и убунту перестал запускаться. При запуске Убунту запускается  emergency mod, но я не смог разобраться в чем проблема. Решил переустановить Windows и после этого поставить Ubuntu 20 lts. Скачал и образы винды и убунту. Создал загрузочные флешки. Когда пытался запустить флешку виндоус в boot-е биос видит надпись uefi. При выборе запускается синий экран и больше ничего. Когда выбераю флешка убунту запускается grub. Помогите пожалуйста, уже мучаюсь 3 день.

Comment: Ставь Ubuntu, забудь о винде — будет тебе счастье.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно определиться - использовать UEFI или нет. Если нет:
выбери в биосе режим legacy для boot media. и для обеех флэшек выбирай не UEFI загрузку. И наоборот.

Иначе если будут использоваться разные технологии не избежать выше описанных проблем.